# Trim space in the variable with PHP not working

Tags: php, base64

I am using PHP to do convert an image to base64 encoding. I am facing a problem to get the $path, because the $path data has space if I put the variable in the $path.

For example I go to echo the $path to see the result is `uploads/ 2007170312_download.jpg`. May I know how to remove space infront of the `2007170312_download.jpg`? I want the expected result is `uploads/2007170312_download.jpg`

Below is my sample coding:

```html
$logo_file_path = '2007170312_download.jpg';
$path = "uploads/".$logo_file_path;
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo $path;
```

What I've tried, but it doesn't work, the result is still remain same:

`trim function`

```html
$path_test = str_replace(' ','',trim($path));
echo $path_test;
```

`urlencode function` , the result is wrong and show me `uploads%2F%0A2007170312_download.jpg`.

```html
$path_test = str_replace(' ','',urlencode($path));
echo $path_test;
```

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: why are you replacing and trimming? just `$path = replace(' ', '', "uploads/".$logo_file_path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove whitespace in your path

```
$logo_file_path = '20 07170312_download.jpg';
$path = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', 'uploads/' . $logo_file_path);

echo $path;
//Output : uploads/2007170312_download.jpg
```

Comment: It was already mentioned they had tried using: `$path_test = str_replace(' ','',trim($path));`, there is no advantage to using `preg_replace` in this specific scenario when `str_replace` didn't. Given they are explicitly looking for whitespace I think `str_replace` would be preferable to `preg_replace`. Save regex calls for when you actually need regex (imo). If this truly resolved the issue, perhaps they had a tab character in the string (in which case I'd argue something is wrong with the input and should be handled earlier).

Comment: After revisiting this, it is plain to see OP is having to deal with a urlencoded newline character (`%0A`). They shouldn't be getting handed file names/paths with new lines in them.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. When I copy-and-paste your code into my IDE (Visual Studio Code) and execute it (with lines 4 and 5 commented out in order to avoid error messages and abortion before reaching the `echo` command) I get the output `uploads/2007170312_download.jpg`, i.e. without any whitespace, in the console.
Apparently there is no reason for using `trim()` or `str_replace()` functions to get the correct path to your data file.

Edit: And, as it is said correctly elsewhere here, `trim()` wouldn't help anyway because it only removes leading and trailing whitespaces but no
whitespaces within a string.

Edit2: Is it possible that you mistakenly have added a leading whitespace to the file name
(i.e. `' 2007170312_download.jpg'` or a trailing whitespace to the directory part of the path
(i.e. `"uploads/ "`) in your original code?

Edit3: But that wouldn't explain why `str_replace()` doesn't work. Executing the following lines

```php
<?php

$logo_file_path = ' 2007170312_download.jpg'; // leading whitespace in string intended
$path = "uploads/ ".$logo_file_path;  // trailing whitespace in string intended
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// $data = file_get_contents($path);
// $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo $path . "\n";

$path_test = str_replace(' ','',trim($path));

echo $path_test;
```

leads to the following output:

```
uploads/  2007170312_download.jpg
uploads/2007170312_download.jpg
```

So your sample code works fine (even though the `trim()` therein has no effect at all and could be omitted), the problem must be somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

I've ran the code you've attached, and there is no possible way in that instance that there is whitespace in the path string, at the beginning or the end (in that example).

`trim` takes whitespace off the beginning and end of a string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

I think there may be some other sort of issue -  as the `str_replace` you used should have successfully removed any whitespace, in any location in the string.

I don't think you want to use `urlencode` here at all.

Can you post an example closer to what is happening?

It can be convenient to print after each statement to see exactly what is happening, e.g.:

```
<?php

  $logo_file_path = 'zzz.jpg';
  $path = "./" . $logo_file_path;
  print $path . "\n";

  $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  print $type . "\n";

  $data = file_get_contents($path);
  $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```